# Facebook embedded Reel?

Tags: facebook-iframe

I already use iframe to embedded Facebook vidéo on my website and it workedfine, but it doesn't with Reel.
Is that logicial?
Is there a way to embedded Reel?
Thanks.

I tried to use the same iframe than video but it failed.

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?height=476&href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fmyaccount%reel%2F12705868508382%2F&show_text=false&width=600&t=0"
   width="600" height="476" 
   style="border:none;overflow:hidden" 
   scrolling="no" frameborder="0" 
   allowfullscreen="true" 
   allow="clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share" 
   allowFullScreen="true">
</iframe>
```